# minimum eigenvalue for difference of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ a symmetric positive definite matrix, and $B$ a matrix constructed from $A$ by setting all its off-diagonal elements to zero. Then is there a way to see for which values of positive scalars $a$ and $b$ $$C=aA-bB$$ is positive definite?

Do we know something on the smallest eigenvalue of $C$?

---

@uranix commented that I could be after some $\epsilon$ such that $\det(A-\epsilon B)=0$ and have $C_{\epsilon}$ be PSD. I looked at $A=[1,1;1,7]$ and found $\epsilon=1.37796$ but then the eigenvalues of $C_{1.37796}$ are $-3.02372$ and $0$ ...

Comment: @uranix just added the word "positive". many thanks for the comment. this makes the problem more clear.

Comment: Then you can divide by $a$ and reduce the problem only to
$$
C = A - \epsilon B
$$

Comment: @uranix that is true, then do we know something about $\epsilon$ for which $C$ is still PD?

Comment: Actually, we know that for $\epsilon = 0$ the matrix is PD, and there is smallest $\epsilon$, for which $\operatorname{det} (A - \epsilon B) = 0$. For that $\epsilon$ the matrix $C$ becomes PSD. The only assumption is that $\lambda_{\min}(\epsilon)$ is a continious function, and its roots are generalized eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ and those are positive reals

Comment: @uranix this helps a lot, could you please explain a bit more, as how do we find this specific $\epsilon$? but why under such a condition $C$ is still PSD? could be that some eigenvalues are negative, no?

Comment: Is $A$ symmetrical by chance?

Comment: oh you are good in shaping my question :-) it is symmetric, see the edit. I also included your previous comment.

Comment: A necessary condition for $A-\epsilon B$ to be SPD is that all diagonal elements are positive. From here it follows $\epsilon<1$. A sufficient condition for $A-\epsilon B$ to be SPD is that it is with a dominant diagonal, i.e when you subtract $\epsilon$ diag$(A)$ you should keep the matrix $A-\epsilon$ diag $A$ with a dominant diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider simplified problem about eigenvalues of
$$
C = A - \epsilon B, \quad A = A^\top > 0
$$
where $B = \operatorname{diag}(A)$.

Let's inspect the equation
$$
\operatorname{det}(A - \epsilon B) = 0.
$$
Since $B$ is a diagonal matrix it is easy to construct $B^{-1/2}$ - matrix with diagonal elements raised in $-1/2$ power.
$$
\operatorname{det}(B^{1/2})
\operatorname{det}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2} - \epsilon)
\operatorname{det}(B^{1/2})
 = 0\\
\operatorname{det}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2} - \epsilon) = 0.
$$

The matrix $G = B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ is positive definite since
$$
x^\top B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}x = (AB^{-1/2}x, B^{-1/2}x) > 0, \quad \forall x \neq 0
$$
Thus all eigenvalues of $G$ are positive, and those are precisely the roots $\epsilon_i$ of 
$$
\operatorname{det}(G - \epsilon) = 0.
$$
Assume that $0 < \epsilon_1 \leq \epsilon_2 \leq \dots \leq \epsilon_n$.

Assuming that $\lambda_{\min}(C)$ is a continuous function of $\epsilon$ (that sounds sane) and obviously $\lambda_{\min}(A) > 0$
the function $$\lambda_{\min}(A - \epsilon B)$$ thus is positive when $0 \leq \epsilon < \epsilon_1$. At $\epsilon = \epsilon_1$ the determinant of the $A - \epsilon B$ vanishes, so $\lambda_{\min}$ can not be positive.

Comment: Many thanks for the discussion and the answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $A-\epsilon B$ is positive definite iff $B^{-\frac{1}{2}}(A-\epsilon B)B^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is positive definite.

Now $B^{-\frac{1}{2}}(A-\epsilon B)B^{-\frac{1}{2}}= B^{-\frac{1}{2}}AB^{-\frac{1}{2}}-\epsilon Id$.

So $B^{-\frac{1}{2}}(A-\epsilon B)B^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is positive definite iff $\epsilon<$ smallest eigenvalue of $B^{-\frac{1}{2}}AB^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer (+1)

Comment: How do you define $B^{-1/2}$ and how do you ensure its existence?

Comment: @A.P. B is the diagonal of a positive definite matrix. So all the coefficients in the diagonal are positive.